# "Could not write the disc image to the device" error when creating an Ubuntu startup USB

Tags: boot, live-usb

I'm following the instructions on installing Ubuntu from USB:

1. I have downloaded the .ISO file.
2. Inserted a 16 GB USB.
3. Launched Startup Disk Creator from the Dash.
4. Followed prompts.

I then get this error:

```
Could not write the disc image (/home/clintonlucas/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) to the device (/dev/sdc).
```

No other info given.

Help please.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running (the host system, where you want to use the Startup Disk Creator)? If you are not sure, please run `lsb_release -a` in a terminal window and edit your original question to add the output. I am asking because there are severe problems with old versions of the Startup Disk Creator, and if that is the problem, I suggest that you install and use mkusb instead. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: The Startup Disk Creator *should* work well in this version of Ubuntu. What is the target device (the USB drive)? How is it connected? What partition table and file system is there? What information is there during the previous steps? Could there be a hardware problem (either with the USB system in the computer or with the USB drive itself)? See this link that might help you analyse the problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: mkusb has worked fine thanks.    USB on /dev/sdc.  Hardware ok as just used ok with mkusb and simply plugged into the USB port on laptop.  USB formatted using the Ubuntu file manager - didn't look to see how it was partitioned.  Thanks for your help - will just use mkusb in future.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :-)